# Set Background Color of a <td> in a @if in Blade Templating

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a Table cell like this:

```
<td>
    @if ($user->status == 1)Present
    @elseif ($user->status_detail != null) Absent(see Details)
    @else Absent
    @endif
</td>
```

So my problem is, I don't want to just give the Table cell the Word "Present" I want to give it also a Color. Do you guys have a suggestion for this problem?

Comment: How about putting the if OUTSIDE of the td and generating it that way?

Comment: I tried that one, but sadly it didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this in  element as in the following example

```
<td class="
@if ($user->status == 1)
present
@else
absent
@endif
">
    @if ($user->status == 1)Present
    @elseif ($user->status_detail != null) Absent(see Details)
    @else Absent
    @endif
</td>
```

And then in CSS you can define styles as you want for example:

```
.present {background:#0f0;}
.absent {background:#f00;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a  tag around the text "Present". then give a class to the span use CSS to give background color to span.

```
<td>
    @if ($user->status == 1)<span class="present">Present</span>
    @elseif ($user->status_detail != null) Absent(see Details)
    @else <span class="absent">Absent</span>
    @endif
</td>
```

In CSS

```
.present{ background:#ff0;display:block; width:100%;}
.absent{ background:#f00;display:block; width:100%;}
```

Comment: With this solution only the "present" has a background color and not the whole table cell.

Comment: add display:block; to the style

Answer (score 0):

```
@if ($user->status == 1) 
   $status = Present;
   $color = "green";
@elseif ($user->status_detail != null) 
   $status = Absent(see Details);
   $color = "red"
@else
   $status = Absent(see Details);
   $color = "red";
@endif

<td style="background-color:{{$color}}">{{$status}}</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<td class="status">
@if ($user->status == 1)Present
@elseif ($user->status_detail != null) Absent(see Details)
@else Absent
@endif
</td>
```

CSS

.status{ background:#fff;}

or should it be different when absent or present?

Comment: It should be a different color.

Comment: colors are editable ofcourse. You can find some here if you still need it: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp

Comment: I mean absent and present should be different colors. But thanks anyways I now have a working solution.